# JQuery Click() function executes only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

In the following code, `CLICK()` method runs only one time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
        var i=0;

        $("#btn").click( function () {
            while(arr[i])
                alert(arr[i++]);
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body> 
    <div id="btn">Click Me</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Whats the problem?
I read all the other subjects but didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

It does: - Just reset your `i` to 0. In your handler the condition fails second time because your `i` becomes `array.length` from your previous execution and it fails, since there is no item at `arr[array.length]` i.e3 in your case.

```
    $("#btn").click(function () {
       while(arr[i])
            alert(arr[i++]);
        i = 0; //here reset it

    });
```

or just move it to the scope of the function.

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
        var i = 0;
           while(arr[i])
                alert(arr[i++]);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The click method runs on every click, but after the first one it doesn't enter while loop anymore, because `i === 3`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
            while(arr[i])
                alert(arr[i++]);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by variable i, please move i to click function, such as:

```
$("#btn").bind('click', function(){
    var i = 0;
    while(arr[i])
        alert(arr[i++]);
});
```